# How to use Py_AddPendingCall

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api, cpython

I have an embedded Python program which runs in a thread in C.

When the Python interpreter switches thread context (yielding control to another thread), I'd like to be notified so I can perform certain necessary operations.

It seems that [`Py_AddPendingCall`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#asynchronous-notifications) is exactly what I'm looking for.  However, the API docs are pretty brief on this function, and I'm confused as to how `Py_AddPendingCall` is supposed to be used.  From reading the docs, my understanding is that:

- A worker thread calls `Py_AddPendingCall` and assigns a handler
  function.
- When the Python interpreter runs, it calls the handler function
  whenever it yields control to another thread
- The handler itself is executed in the *main* interpreter thread, with
  the GIL acquired

I've googled around for example code showing how to use `Py_AddPendingCall`, but I can't find anything.  My own attempt to use it simply doesn't work.  The handler is just never called.

My worker thread code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char* PYTHON_CODE = 
"while True:\n"
"   for i in range(0,10): print(i)\n"
"\n";

int handler(void* arg)
{
    printf("Pending Call invoked!\n");
    abort();
}

void* worker_thread(void*)
{
    PyGILState_STATE state = PyGILState_Ensure();
    int res = Py_AddPendingCall(&func, nullptr);
    cout << "Result: " << res << endl;
    PyRun_SimpleString(CODE);
    PyGILState_Release(state);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyEval_InitThreads();
    PyEval_ReleaseLock();

    pthread_t threads[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], 0, worker_thread, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) pthread_join(threads[i], 0);

    Py_Finalize();
}
```

In this example, `worker_thread` is invoked in C as a pthread worker thread.  In this test I run 4 worker threads, so some context switching should happen.  This loops infinitely, but the pending call handler is never invoked.

So, can someone provide a minimal working example that shows how `Py_AddPendingCall` is supposed to be used?

Comment: @nneoneo - it is called from a `pthread` worker thread via `pthread_create`

Comment: Does your main thread execute Python code at all? Are you embedding or extending Python?

Comment: I'm embedding Python - the worker threads call Python code, but the main thread doesn't.

Comment: Please post a _complete_ example that fails to work. I tried your code, modified to include a `main()` that initializes Python and call test_thread(), and it invoked the handler. I then modified it to actually start a thread, and invoke test_thread in the other thread, and it still invoked the handler. See http://pastebin.com/pQrnHEFX

Comment: @user4815162342: Your example doesn't initialize any Python threads -- there's still only one thread in Python's view.

Comment: A complete example would still be useful. Your snippet is misleading in that it looks like it's (almost) complete, while it requires further setup to test.

Comment: @user4815162342 - okay, I posted a complete example

Comment: What sort of necessary operations need to be performed on every context switch between threads? Seems like an unnecessary overhead...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pending calls are only executed on the main thread, and the main thread can only service pending calls when it executes Python code. So, the main thread must be running an interpreter loop in order to service any pending calls. From `Python/ceval.c`:

```
Py_MakePendingCalls(void)
{
    ...

    /* only service pending calls on main thread */
    if (main_thread && PyThread_get_thread_ident() != main_thread)
        return 0;

    ...
}
```

In an embedding scenario, the "main thread" is whichever thread calls `PyEval_InitThreads` (note that it is also automatically called the first time you start a thread from Python code). Since your main thread sits in `pthread_join`, it is not executing Python code and therefore not dispatching pending calls.

Note too that the handler only executes when control is handed to the main thread -- the handler doesn't run if control goes from one worker to another. So, `Py_MakePendingCalls` is probably not an appropriate interface to use for this task.